# Is it possible to kill a Weeping Angel?

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

I couldn't find this question on here when I searched so its probably really stupid but:

Surely when an Angel is quantum-locked its literally just stone, so why can you not simply smash it with another rock or a hammer -- surely that would destroy it?

Comment: Quantum locking is for defense which was there to protect them from everything...

Comment: Assuming you could smash it with a hammer ... don't blink. You'd be REALLY close to it.

Answer (score 42):

**I wouldn't stake my life on how effective a sledgehammer might be. These are creatures the Time Lords, masters of time and space, discoverers of the temporal vortex, and creators of the TARDIS, feared. Officially, there is no word on whether your idea of smashing them with a hammer would work. But no weapon ever deployed against them, in the television series, has ever been seen to be effective.**

But we can infer from the interactions we have had with the Doctor and the Angels that they might simply be tougher than they would appear even if they look to be made of stone or a stone-like material. We have also seen them animate, possess or even transfer themselves to other objects and materials such as the Statue of Liberty. ([The Angels Take Manhattan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Angels_Take_Manhattan))

[image: Weeping Angel Statue of Liberty]

*I always wanted to see the Statue of Liberty. Now I will never make that trip...Thanks Dr. Who.*

- Officially the Weeping Angels evolved to be the way they are and were contemporaries of the Time Lords. This means the species is tens of millions of years old. Were they technologically sophisticated at one time and enhanced themselves this way? Are the the product of selective breeding? Were they warped by the Time Vortex. They are so old, their origins are unknown to anyone living except maybe themselves and the Time Lords.
- We have never seen the Doctor personally take up arms against them physically. Being stronger and faster than any human, he is still careful to avoid coming into contact with them. When Father Octavian was grabbed, the Doctor lacked the strength to free him; a bad sign. ([The Time of Angels](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Time_of_Angels))
- We have seen assault weapons used against them with little or no effect, indicating a level of toughness that might exceed the damage dealing capacity of 51st Century projectile weaponry. ([The Time of Angels](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Time_of_Angels))
- They are resistant to wide ranges of radiation and hostile environments indicating while they resemble stone, they are made of a material as tough or tougher than the granite or marble they appear to be made of. However, they can be poisoned by tainting temporal energies using paradox ([The Angels Take Manhattan](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Angels_Take_Manhattan))
- And finally, we have no idea what the effect which causes them to be unable to move, i.e. "quantum-locking", actually is. If, for example, it is a form of temporal stasis which freezes them outside of time, then, in theory, very few things could damage them at all while they are locked.

I tend to take the Doctor's reaction to things as a sign of whether you should be a little afraid or a lot. Only a few things have ever made the Doctor hesitate, the Daleks, the Cybermen, the [Vashta Nerada](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Vashta_Nerada) and the [Weeping Angels](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Weeping_Angel) are samples of creatures he is happy if he never sees again. I would take the advice of everyone who has survived an encounter with them. Don't blink. Not even for a second. Run as fast as you can.

Comment: Note that the Tenth Doctor's exact comment to Sally Sparrow is "you can't kill a stone". AFAIK we've never seen a dead Angel, only ones eliminated via other means (crack in time, time paradox, etc.)

Comment: As far as I recall Mr Grayle from "Angels take Manhattan" was particularly afraid of the weeping angels because he had hurt/damaged one of them (with 1930 tech no less, because he wanted to know if "they can feel pain"). So they are at least vulnerable to some extent. But given how they recovered from damage in previous episodes this probably still doesn't mean they can be killed (based on episodes so far, future plot requirements might prove hazardous to their immortality).

Comment: I think in a Doctor Who special written by the kids, Doctor destroyed a Weeping Angel with sonic screwdriver. But that probably isn't considered canon.

Answer (score 6):

I am unsure whether it is possible to kill a weeping angel, but there is *some* way to neutralize them, although what that means (whether to render them harmless or to kill them) is is unknown.

From The Time of Angels:

> OCTAVIAN: The Angel, as far as we know, is still trapped in the ship. Our mission is to get inside and neutralise it.
>   <sub>[The Doctor Who Transcripts](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/31-4.htm)</sub>

Octavian and his clerics must have had some idea how to go about this, although that plan was never mentioned. Possibly whatever tool(s) would have been used were on Bob or one of the other clerics killed early on.

Starvation might be a way to kill them, but that would likely take hundreds, if not thousands of years. Again from The Time of Angels:

> DOCTOR: Dinner to an Angel. The longer we leave it there, the stronger it will grow. Who built that temple? Are they still around?
>   RIVER: The Aplans. Indigenous life form. They died out four hundred years ago.
>   ...
>   DOCTOR: The Aplans. What happened? How did they die out?
>   RIVER: Nobody knows.
>   DOCTOR: We know.
>   OCTAVIAN: They don't look like Angels.
>   AMY: And they're not fast. You said they were fast. They should have had us by now.
>   DOCTOR: Look at them. They're dying, losing their form. They must have been down here for centuries, starving.
>   AMY: Losing their image?
>   DOCTOR: And their image is their power. Power. Power!
>   <sub>[The Doctor Who Transcripts](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/31-4.htm)</sub>

So we learn that as a Weeping Angel starves its rock form will begin to degrade. After 400 years they still look humanoid but their features are indistinguishable. Presumably this is similar to a human emaciating, getting thin and weak. Whether they would ever actually die or not from starvation is unknown.

Comment: Hmm, by the end of that last quote, given an Angel's image is its power and its being, then simply grinding an Angel down to dust while it is in rock form should - theoretically - be enough to "neutralize" it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe this is ever addressed in canon, but I think an argument can be made that the statue itself is not the "Weeping Angel." I say this because of the episode where merely seeing the recording of the angel had the same effect as encountering a physical weeping angel. I would theorize that the statues are merely a conveyance of sorts, which is why in the series virtually any statue became one of these creatures, and that the actual malevolent being is a noncorporeal being that uses these vessels to interact with the corporeal world.

Comment: Maybe. The actual quote from that episode (*The Time of Angels*) is “That which holds the image of an Angel becomes itself an Angel”. That suggests that encountering the recording doesn’t have the same effect as encountering an Angel; but the recording of the Angel became *another* Angel — SPOILER ALERT as did Amy after the recording Angel was reflected in her eye.

Comment: Making the Statue of Liberty a Weeping Angel + that quote about images of angels becoming angels really messed things up.  Postcards and snowglobes from New York all over the world would be turning into angels left and right.

Comment: I have always imagined that only images of moving angels become angels themselves; the recording Amy was watching must have caught a frame of the angel in motion. This is why it only invaded her mind when she looked at it close enough to catch a glimpse of the angel's movement through the static. It also explains why seeing an angel up close in person does not normally cause it to invade your consciousness.

Answer (score 1):

River had to jack up her arm to free herself from an angel. If it was that easy to destroy them, she would have just smashed it, instead of hurting herself.Although, this incident was a fixed point in time and River knew that Amy read that River had broken her own wrist to free herself.

Comment: Well, the Angel had her held in the middle of a room, probably not with any smashing implements in reach. And I'd imagine they are rather heavy, and probably not that easy to move... especially if you're trying to move it from such an awkward pose/stance.

Comment: This is wrong.  River and the Doctor both as much as state that they could have harmed the Angel to free River, if Amy hadn't have read it first.   Such a terrible episode...